# Random Client-initiated push isn't enabled Error - Parse IOS

Tags: ios, parsing, push-notification, parse-platform

I randomly get this error while pushing messages from ios device to another ios device. I have double checked and I can confirm that in the Parse dashboard settings, I have indeed enabled client initiated push. The strange part is that the push sometimes works and sometimes it does not, kind of random. Does anyone have any clue why this is happening? I have been banging my head about this issue since the last couple of days, any help is highly appreciated.

Error: Client-initiated push isn't enabled. (Code: 115, Version: 1.2.20)

Thanks,
Jack.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you are sending too many consecutive messages at one time. I was also having this problem when testing notifications sent from one iOS device to another. Check the Push Notification dashboard and you might see that the one's that are not going through don't have an iOS icon as a segment in the Target column.